# Error with Store

Tags: redux, store

It's my error:

[image]

And it's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './_helpers';

import {App} from './App';


render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It's my store i export and import it to App.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer, // mounted under "form"
});


const store = (window.devToolsExtension

  ? window.devToolsExtension()(createStore)
  : createStore)(reducer);

export default store;
```

Where should i add store with Provider to works well?

---

I change structure of store and now it's working:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../_reducers';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    )
));
```

Comment: Can you upload the code of your store in your helper?

Comment: I see you export default store, so you must import it by import store from '._helpers';. Hope it helps

Comment: it's better if you update the question with your code, instead of adding it as a comment

Comment: Ok sorry, i uploading it. When i change 'store' from store it's still not working

Comment: I change structure of store:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are exporting store as default you have to import it without courly braces as follow:

```
import store from './_helpers';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your help :)

I just change structure of store and files to make it works, problem was in reducers and architecture :)